# Login screen loads a blank activity at first time

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm doing an app that has a LOGIN screen and a SECOND screen with information.

The username and password are checked from a JSON. After that, an intent jump the activity to ApprovalsActivity.class, which is going to show in a LISTVIEW the items from a second JSON.

It's like a help desk system showing the tasks you have after you logged in.

Everything works (thanks StackOverFlow xD) but ONLY after the second time the user logs in.

So, when I first click login, the app jump activity but to a blank one. If I click the BACK button and login again, the items in the listview appear.

Could anyone help me with this? It's my first time doing something more complicated with JSON.

MainActivity (LoginScreen):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText usernameWidget;
EditText passwordWidget;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    usernameWidget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
    passwordWidget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_password);

}// END ON CREATE

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String message = "message";
    String loginSuccess;
    String pessoaFisicaId = "PessoaFisicaId";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data; // each time creates a char current

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }   // END doInBackground


    //Method called when the doInBack is complete
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            loginSuccess = jsonObject.getString("success");
            pessoaFisicaId = jsonObject.getString("PessoaFisicaId");
            message = jsonObject.getString("message");

        }catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//  END CATCH

        if (loginSuccess.contains("true")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApprovalsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pessoaFisicaId", pessoaFisicaId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if (loginSuccess.contains("false")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }// END POST EXECUTE
}// END Download Task

public void login(View view) {
    String user = usernameWidget.getText().toString();
    String pass = passwordWidget.getText().toString();

    String stringJSON = "URLHIDDENlogin=" + user + "&senha=" + pass;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute(stringJSON);
}// END LOGIN
```

ApprovalsActivity(After Login Screen passed with correct user and password):

```
public class ApprovalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static List<String> getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> getSolicitanteStringListFromJsonArray = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> getItemStringListFromJsonArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public static String chamado;
public static String solicitante;
public static String itemDeCatalogo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aprovacoes);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String pessoaFisicaId = intent.getExtras().getString("pessoaFisicaId");

    String stringJSON = "URLHIDDEN" + pessoaFisicaId;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute(stringJSON);

    ListView listApprovals = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_aprovacoes);
    CustomizedListClass customizedListView = new CustomizedListClass(ApprovalsActivity.this);
    listApprovals.setAdapter(customizedListView); //Layout inflator

    listApprovals.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.aprovacoes_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data; // each time creates a char current

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dados");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonPart = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                chamado = jsonPart.getString("Chamado");
                solicitante = jsonPart.getString("Solicitante");
                itemDeCatalogo = jsonPart.getString("ItemDeCatalogo");

                getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray.add(chamado);
                Log.i("****getChamado", String.valueOf(getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray));
                getSolicitanteStringListFromJsonArray.add(solicitante);
                Log.i("****getsolicitante", String.valueOf(getSolicitanteStringListFromJsonArray));
                getItemStringListFromJsonArray.add(itemDeCatalogo);
                Log.i("****getItem", String.valueOf(getItemStringListFromJsonArray));

            }
        }catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//  END CATCH

        return result;
    }   // END doInBackground

    //Method called when the doInBack is complete
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }// END POST EXECUTE
}// END Download Task
```

}

CustomizedListClass(Show the items on the list):

```
public class CustomizedListClass extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

TextView txtChamado;
TextView txtSolicitante;
TextView txtItemDeCatalogo;

public CustomizedListClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    //Instantiate the layoutinflater object to use the layout inflater service on a object context
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() { //count the objects
    return getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray.size(); //return the length of the array
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) { //gets an specific item in the array
    return position; //return the specific value in array animalImages in the position position(variable)
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) { //returns the item ID of our objects
    return position; //The ID is the position of the item in the array
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customized_list_view, null);

    txtChamado = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtChamado);
    txtSolicitante = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSolicitante);
    txtItemDeCatalogo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDeCatalogo);


    String oldChamado = txtChamado.getText().toString();
    String newChamado = getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray.get(position);
    txtChamado.setText(oldChamado + newChamado);

    String oldSolicitante = txtSolicitante.getText().toString();
    String newSolicitante = getSolicitanteStringListFromJsonArray.get(position);
    txtSolicitante.setText(oldSolicitante + newSolicitante);

    String oldItemDeCatalogo = txtItemDeCatalogo.getText().toString();
    String newItemDeCatalogo = getItemStringListFromJsonArray.get(position);
    txtItemDeCatalogo.setText(oldItemDeCatalogo + newItemDeCatalogo);


    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+ getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    return view;
}// END METHOD
}
```

SOLUTION:

Add customizedListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); after the line:

```
getItemStringListFromJsonArray.add(itemDeCatalogo);
                Log.i("****getItem", String.valueOf(getItemStringListFromJsonArray));
```

on the OnPostExecute, so the listview adapter will know something changed and has to be updated.

Also declare:

```
 CustomizedListClass customizedListView;
```

Outside the OnCreate.

Comment: so on the first attempt it works right,but consecutive tries does not?

Comment: On the contrary. The 1st attempt goes to a blank screen. The second goes to the right screen, the listview.

Comment: Have you looked into the transition from the screens? When you transition from view A(login) to View B(ListView), is everything set up correctly? Do you do the same thing both times? Consider adding logging(System.out.println() or Log.e("debugger", [message])) so you can see where/if something doesn't function correctly.

Comment: I could see with Log.i that the arrays start filling values one by one and they repeat it a lot. 
Like getChamadoStringListFromJsonArray.add(chamado);

adds value1, then value2, etc. and in the end has all values but it get the values in a loop, repeating the final array in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have tried to execute the task after the listview is initialized.
Or try to call adapter notifyDataSetChanged after the task end on onPoastExecutre..

Comment: After I click login the intent jumps to the activity with the listview. I didn't use notifyDataSetChanged. Should I? (I don't recall correctly how to use it but I know it solves some problems).

Comment: I  believe that a call to notifyDataSetChanged  will solve your problem.

Comment: Your task most probably will ends after your activity is created and the list is already loaded. When task ends even is your data list contain new data the list view/adapter should be notified that the data set was changed, and that will make the listview to load the "new" items.

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my day xD